# Java regex zero-width positive lookahead

Tags: java, regex

In the [java reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the expression `(?=X)` is documented as

> X, via zero-width positive lookahead

What does it mean, how does it work?

Comment: In short: the char immediately to the right of the current location must be `X`, but do not put the `X` into the match value. Also, see [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).